# Change object variables in a list

Tags: python-3.x

After a break of some years I´m playing around with some Python 3 code. I have problems changing the items of a list containing object variables. I´ve only used Python 2 before. Does this work differently in Python 3?

```py
import random

class Variabletest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vara = 0
        self.varb = 0
        self.varc = 0

    def setvariables(self):
        variables = [self.vara, self.varb, self.varc]
        for variable in variables:
            variable = random.randrange(0, 10)
        print(variables)

test = Variabletest()
test.setvariables()
```

I expect the output to be 3 random numbers in rang 0...10, but I only get [0, 0, 0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remember that arguments are passed by assignment in Python.

Why it is not possible the way you do:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = [a, b]
print(c[0] is a) # Here c[0] is a
c[0] = 2         # Here c[0] become 2, and since a is not 2
print(c[0] is a) # c[0] is not a
print(c, a)
```

Output:

```
True
False
2 1
```

But you can directly change the object attribute with this:

```
import random


class VariableTest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_a, self.var_b, self.var_c = 0, 0, 0

    def set_variable(self):
        self.var_a, self.var_b, self.var_c = [random.randrange(0, 10) for _ in
                                              range(3)]
        print(self.var_a, self.var_b, self.var_c)


a = test()
a.set_variable()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't work because you're only modifying the iterator, you're not modifying the variables `self.vara`, `self.varb` and `self.varc`.
Try using:

```
import random

class Variabletest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vara = 0
        self.varb = 0
        self.varc = 0

    def setvariables(self):
        self.vara, self.varb, self.varc = random.randrange(0, 10), random.randrange(0, 10), random.randrange(0, 10)
        print([self.vara, self.varb, self.varc])

test = Variabletest()
test.setvariables()
```